# Why can't I suggest an edit on some questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I was going to suggest an edit on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/368/where-the-wild-things-are), but I don't see an edit button anywhere. I tried [going to it directly](https://movies.stackexchange.com/posts/368/edit), and I just get a "Page Not Found" error. It also seems to happen on [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/373/period-film-with-king-in-medical-contraption) and [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/369/opening-quote-from-movie-apocalypto) too. I don't have edit privileges, but why can't I at least suggest one?

Edit: All those have been edited by someone else now, and now I can edit them all. I'm still wondering why that happened, but I can't find more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot submit a suggested edit if **another suggested edit is already pending on that post**. The initial suggestion must be approved or rejected before the new suggestion can be made. All three of the examples you've shown all include a suggested edit from another user, so the likely scenario is that you attempted to suggest an edit while someone else was already doing so.

Comment: Thanks, Grace. That's what I thought it might be, but I wasn't sure.